# How to start search dialog in a new Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to implement a search function in my Android application. I would like to have the "Search" hardware button **launch a new Activity** with the standard search dialog already displayed. I guess I could do it manually, but maybe there is a way to do this using the standard Search dialog?

Here is what I do:

In the MainActivity I hijack the search button, like this:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (KeyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH && event.getRepeatCount() == 0){
        Intent i = new Intent(Month.this, SearchActivity.class);
        i.setAction("android.intent.action.SEARCH");
        startActivity(i);           
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(KeyCode, event);
}
```

In the Android Manifest.xml, in the SearchActivity section I have this:

```
        <activity android:name=".SearchActivity"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                        android:launchMode="singleTop"
                        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
              android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>

    </activity>
```

And in the MainActivity section:

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
                    <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                            android:value=".SearchActivity" />

    </activity>
```

I assumed, that sending the *android.intent.action.SEARCH* to the SearchActivity should open the Search Dialog. But it does not.... SearchActivity is displayed, but I have to press Search button again to see the Search dialog. 
What am I missing?

Comment: add this method in your activity `@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {

return super.onSearchRequested();
}`

Answer (score 0):

(This is just a bit too long for a comment.)

What does logcat say? Failed intent invocation should have a stack trace. Also, I suggest you read the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) more carefully. For example, you don't have to intercept the search button event as it opens the search dialog by default anyway. You should also check if you have the [searchable configuration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html). If you want to start the search dialog from another activity, make sure you have [this markup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchDialog) in your activity's declaration.

Comment: I know that search button opens the search by default, but it does that in the **current** activity, which is not I want to do. I want the new activity to be created. As for the _android.app.default_searchable_ tag, I do have it (I edited my original question and added this info).

Comment: LogCat does not say anything - the SearchActivity is just launched, but with no Search Dialog. I must press the Search button again, to display search dialog.